# how to check whether a unix path is valid or not in unix using c#

Tags: c#

i am transferring some file to unix using my dot net code.I am asking the user to enter the unix path where he wants to transfer the file. before transferring the file I want to check whether the path user has entered is valid or not.

```
 try
      {
                Process objProcess = new Process();
                objProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "putty.exe";
                objProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = txtUserName.Text.Trim() + "@" + cmbIP.Text.Trim() + " -pw " + txtPassword.Text.Trim() + " -m \"" + CodeSetFileNameTemp + "\"";
                objProcess.Start();

                objProcess.WaitForExit();

                SUCCEEDED.AppendLine(viewName);
                SELECTED.Remove(SELECTED.ToString().IndexOf(viewName), viewName.Length + 2);


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                FAILED.AppendLine(viewName);
                SELECTED.Remove(SELECTED.ToString().IndexOf(viewName), viewName.Length + 2);
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + ". Unable to connect UNIX", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                return false;
            }
```

Comment: `Regex` would be the best chice for this..?

Answer (score 1):

Just transfer the file. If there is a problem, you'll get an error of some sort. There's any number of reasons why such a transfer would fail (network problem, bad path, incorrect permissions, insufficient space and so on) and no pre-checking of the entered path will help you out there. Even if you *could* validate the path, there's no guarantee that things won't change between validation and attempted transfer.

This is similar to those who want a valid email address regex, seemingly unaware that even a correctly formed address may be invalid simply because there no email account behind it.

UNIX allows a *very* wide range of characters in path names, even such heinous things as backspaces and other control characters. I wouldn't use them all myself but they *are* valid.

So, bottom line, best way to check if a target location can be used is to use it in the manner you desire.

---

Based on your comment that no error detection is available, I believe the best approach is to send the file over then read it back into a different file.

That's the *only* way you can be certain that the file has been delivered complete and correct. Every other option that springs to mind (including simply checking for a valid path) will leave some uncertainty.

For example, `/home/pax` is well and truly a valid path under UNIX yet may not even exist on th target box. Even if it *does* exist, the transfer may fail halfway through and you will have no indication of that, other than if you bring back the file and compare it to the original.

Comment: actually i am using putty to transfer yhe files and it doesnot throw any error if path does not exists                                                               Process objProcess = new Process();
                    objProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "putty.exe";
                    objProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = txtUserName.Text.Trim() + "@" + cmbIP.Text.Trim() + " -pw " + txtPassword.Text.Trim() + " -m \"" + CodeSetFileNameTemp + "\"";
                    objProcess.Start();

Comment: Then, in cases where no error is detectable, the only way to be sure is to send the file over then get it back with a different name and compare them. That way, you can be certain that the complete file showed up at the right place. I'll update the answer.

Comment: how to get back the file from unix srver i am very new at dot net so plz give some more info

Comment: @nishan, you would get the file back the same way you're sending it over, with `putty` (or, more likely, `pscp`). It can send files _both_ ways.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Directory.Exists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.exists.aspx).

That will tell you if the directory entered actually exists.  Beyond that, other things (permissions) can still go wrong.

Answer (score 1):

What method are you using to transfer the files to the Unix server?  If you're mounting it as a network drive using Samba, you can use [System.IO.Directory.Exists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.exists.aspx) to determine if the path is valid or not.  If it's something like FTP you can try to list the directory, and catch the exception for it not being there.

Comment: i am using puttty to transfer the files

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are taking a Directories path from your user than you can use
this

```
Directory.Exists(path);
```

It will return a boolean value flags the existence of the path provided.